# Need to count how many child tag in kml files

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml, kml

I have some work to convert kml files and insert to mysql database
I have a little bit confuse to count how many child tag **folder** under my kml files
here is a little kml files

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
 <name>FTTH 5 Cities 60K 20150409.kmz</name>
 <open>1</open>
 <Folder>
  <name>Kebun Jeruk, Jakarta</name>
  <Folder>
   <name>olt</name>
  </Folder>
  <Folder>
   <name>FEEDER</name>
  </Folder>
 </Folder>
 <Folder>
  <name>Kebun Jahe, Jakarta</name>
  <Folder>
   <name>olt</name>
  </Folder>
 </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

and here is another one

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
 <name>FTTH 5 Cities 60K 20150409.kmz</name>
 <open>1</open>
 <Folder>
  <name>Kebun Jeruk, Jakarta</name>
  <Folder>
   <name>olt</name>
  </Folder>
  <Folder>
   <name>FEEDER</name>
  </Folder>
  <Folder>
   <name>CLUSTER FTTH KEBUN JERUK</name>
  </Folder>
 </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

my present code to count is

```html
$file = $_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'];
$xml_file = file_get_contents($file);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_file);
$decodearray = json_decode(json_encode((array)$xml),1);

echo count($decodearray['Document']['Folder']);
```

need to count child **Folder** tag of **Document->Folder(1st)** ignore other
result I got from both kml file is **2** shold be **3** from another sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally little trick I found do the result

```html
$file = 'file.kml';
$xml_file = file_get_contents($file);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_file);
$decodearray = json_decode(json_encode((array)$xml),1);

$nowdatetime = date_create();
$tstamp = date_timestamp_get($nowdatetime);

switch (!isset($decodearray['Document']['Folder'][0])) {
  case true:
    $docfolder = $decodearray['Document']['Folder'];
    break;
  case false:
    $docfolder = $decodearray['Document']['Folder'][0];
    break;
}
echo count($docfolder['Folder']);
```

simple switch case to indexing array help much..